# Angular js local variable in different angular apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-routing

I want a way to store a local variable that will remain there even if I changed the path ( The page) or the angular app. I tried $window.localStorage.set and get item and they didn't work as well as rootScope and $window.variable

Comment: what about using localStorage? - I feel is the only option you can use when changin angular app. Also, what do you mean by changing the angular app ? You want to persist something accross different apps ?

Comment: yes like a variable that I can access from different angular apps and I used localStorage, I edited the question

Comment: is this like an environment variable? or something dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the values in local storage you would use:

```
localStorage.setItem({identifier}, {value});
```

Then to retrieve your value you would use:

```
localStorage.getItem({identifier});
```

Comment: I can't send objects using this way I can only send a single variable

Comment: @MahmoudYoussef You are storing the value in local storage and you access it with the identifier. What do you mean you cannot store an object this way?

Comment: The issue is solved what I meant was that I couldn't send an object through this method but it turned out I can. What I meant by Object is an array of any type not only a string